# How to autocomplete multiple fields on php form when a value is selected

Tags: php, forms

I'm certain this is quite simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I've got a form to complete. I want to save other fields from the array corresponding to a selected value.

These values are being passed to the form:

```
$courses =   //a nested array
return view ('moodle_courses.create', compact('courses'));
```

The form is:

```
{{Form::open(['action'=> '', 'method' => 'POST'])}}
    <div><select class='form-control select2' name='fullname'>
    <option  disabled selected value></option>
        @foreach ($courses as $course)
            <option value="{{$course['fullname']}}">{{$course['fullname']}}</option>
        @endforeach</select></div>
    {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

I want to save other values like `$course['description']` or `$course['id']` when `$course['fullname']` is selected without displaying them on the form.

A sample of the array looks like:

```
  Array
   ([0] => Array
        ([id] => 1 
         [shortname] => ...
         [fullname] => ...
         [displayname] => ...
    )
     [1] => Array
         ([id] => 2
          [shortname] => ...
          [fullname] => ...
        [displayname] => ...
    )
)
```